# Implementing specific java MaxHeap using priorityQueue

Tags: java, heap, heapsort

I am going to implement specific java maxHeap using priorityQueue as follows:
Suppose I have a "Customer" class which has a double variable name "marginalGain".

```
PriorityQueue<Customer> marginalGainHeap=new PriorityQueue<Customer>();
```

How can I heapify "marginalGainHeap" using the natural order of "marginalGain" variable? Is it possible with using PriorityQueue or I need to re-implement MaxHeap myself?

Regards.

Comment: Does your `Customer` implement `Comparable`?

Comment: Well then you can still write a custom `Comparator`, and pass that as an argument when building the queue; it will require that you set an initial capacity though.

Comment: Initial capacity is unknown so maybe I go with changing Customer class.(Changing that is expensive but if it is my only choice I will do that) What method should I add to Customer? Could you please explain that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PriorityQueue, however it is worth remembering only the first entry will be sorted.  Most likely you want TreeSet as a SortedSet.

In any case you will need to make Customer Comparable, or a better solution more likely it is good idea to create a `Comparator<Customer>` as you might want to sort Customers in more than one order.  Note: You will want to order all Customers, i.e. even if their marginGain is the same, you need to give them an order.

You can use a Comparator with PriorityQueue like this.

```
PriorityQueue<Customer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Customer>(new Comparator<Customer>() {
    public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
       return Double.compare(c1.getMarginGain(), c2.getMarginGain());
    }
});
```

An advantage of PriorityQueue is you don't have to ensure the comparator doesn't return 0 for different Customers (in a TreeSet it would treat these as duplicates and discard them)

Comment: "however it is worth remembering only the first entry will be sorted" <-- uh, what do you mean?

Comment: @fge PriorityQueue guarantees the first entry is the lowest, but if you iterate over it, later entries can be in any order.

Comment: The maximum one is enough for me. Would you please tell me how can I add comparator?

Comment: @Alin Added an example of a comparator.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write a class implementing max heap using PriroityQueue, as follows, which might be of help for your problem:

```
class MaxHeapUsingPriorityQueue<T>{
int capacity;
Comparator<T> pqc;
Queue<T> q;
public MaxHeapUsingPriorityQueue(int capacity, Comparator<T> comparator){
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.pqc = comparator;
    q = new PriorityQueue<T>(comparator);
}

void add(T t){
    if(q.size() < capacity) q.offer(t);
    else{
        if(pqc.compare(t, q.peek()) > 0){
            q.poll();
            q.offer(t);
        }
    }
}

void displayMaxHeapContent(){
    // in ascending order
    while(!q.isEmpty()) System.out.println(q.poll().toString());
}
```

}